# Select MAX value from length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of names in my table, I want to know which name is the longest.

```
select  max(len(firstname)) from NAMES
```

This give me the biggest value with issues, but If I add the column firsttname to know which name is it near the select statement, It give me an error that its not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I however don't see the use of Group by in this case If the names are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the work

```
SELECT TOP 1 With Ties firstname, len(firstname) as Length
FROM NAMES 
ORDER BY len(firstname) DESC
```

Comment: Its actually `SELECT TOP 1 firstname ,len(firstname)
FROM NAMES 
ORDER BY len(firstname) DESC` as I want to display both the length and name. Thanks !

Comment: If you want all names with the same length that are longest, use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

Comment: @gordon Why did you put brackets around the `1`?

Comment: @Bohemian:its just optional,you can keep in normal way like top 1 as well

Comment: @Bohemian . . . If you look at the syntax diagram (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql), you'll see they are not optional.  I'm not sure why it works *without* the parentheses.

Comment: From the documentation: 
`For backward compatibility, the parentheses are optional in SELECT statements. We recommend that you always use parentheses for TOP in SELECT statements for consistency with its required use in INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, and DELETE statements in which the parentheses are required. `